# Adapted Roll measure implementation

Tags: finance-mathematics, market-microstructure, statistical-finance, prediction

I'm currently trying to implement the roll measure adapted by Easley et al. (2020, p. 22).
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3345183

The adapted roll measure is given by the eq below.

[image]

However, I do not understand how to implement it. Firstly looking at Delta Pt, I am under the understanding the delta (small) pt is a regular change in value from the day before until "this" day. How should I implement the Delta_Pt-w and Delta pt-w+1?

Would the lookback window W, in this case, be a number such as 10? or is it the avg value of the days in those ten days? Do the brackets in this case mean I should add all of the variables together?

The data used for this project is crypto currency OHLCV  retrived from Coinapi.oi. (Sample below)

[image]

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: The Roll measure (named after Prof Richard Roll) is based on autocovariance at lag 1 of price changes. Suppose to keep it simple W=5 and the last 6 price changes (from oldest to most recent) are -3,+5,-7,+2,+1,+8. Then you compute COVARIANCE([-3,+5,-7,+2,+1], [+5,-7,+2,+1,+8]). Both vectors are of length 5 and one is a lagged version of the other (one value was dropped and one was added). The most recent 5 changes vs 5 changes that we had available one period ago. Next you take the absolute value of this covariance, take the square root and multiply by 2.

Comment: Thanks ill try to implement it with that logic